# Any tools to develop asp.net core on MAC/Linux OS?

Tags: ide, asp.net-core, .net-core, linux

I am looking for a tool to develop ASP.NET core on MAC/Linux OS. Visual Studio Code is not a truly IDE. It is more like text editor.

Do you know any tools to develop Asp.NET Core on MAC/Linux OS? Thanks!

Comment: Downvote without any comment?

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Note: I did not down vote. I did vote to close based on SO rules

Comment: @Nkosi: Well, if you search "Any tools" on this site, you will see a ton of similar questions

Comment: Was just trying to explain that It could be why someone down-voted. And the majority of the posts you mentioned are on hold or closed. My comment was quoted from the close panel. Just stating what was there.

Answer (score 2):

Well ... To My understanding that restriction will limit yourself to [JetBrains Rider](https://www.jetbrains.com/rider/) and [Xamarin Studio](https://www.xamarin.com/studio). No other tools support modern .NET development afaik.

Have not used any of them. Also I do not think they offer much more in regards of code editing than VS Code with the c# plugin (which deliver real intellisense and debugging etc). They shine for other features like ui designers etc. And modern ASP.NET development has no designer support beyond templating.